# Pivot Script Producer - Bug Found

Tags: codefluent

I'm sorry to have to submit through this channel.
The report issue feature on your website won't just let me submit my request. Error enclosed:

```
SoftFluent, SoftFluent, we have a problem! An unidentified error has occured
```

**Problem:** Pivot Script producer crashes

**Reproductible:** Yes

**Use case:** 
Basic use case is having 2 entities named the same (concept is the same but spreaded over different namespace and schema), yet referencing a third entity.

After extending SqlPivotProducer, it appears that referenced table would find its constraints (1 PK and 2 FK) but one of the 2 FK would have a null ReferenceTable leading to nullpointer.

**Steps to reproduce:** 
Have this model below and try to generate Pivot Script File

```
<cf:project defaultNamespace="Model1" xmlns:cf="http://www.softfluent.com/codefluent/2005/1" xmlns:cfx="http://www.softfluent.com/codefluent/modeler/2008/1" xmlns:cfsps="http://www.softfluent.com/codefluent/producers.sqlpivotscript/2013/1" xmlns:cfps="http://www.softfluent.com/codefluent/producers.sqlserver/2005/1" xmlns:cfspsi="http://www.softfluent.com/codefluent/producers.ixcyssqlpivotscript/2016/1" createDefaultMethodForms="true" createDefaultApplication="false" createDefaultHints="false">
  <cf:import path="Default.Surface.cfp" />
  <cf:entity name="Entity" schema="SchemaA" namespace="Model1.NamespaceA" persistenceName="Entity">
    <cf:property name="EntityId" key="true" />
    <cf:property name="EntityC" typeName="{0}.NamespaceC.EntityC" />
  </cf:entity>
  <cf:entity name="Entity" schema="SchemaB" namespace="Model1.NamespaceB" persistenceName="Entity">
    <cf:property name="EntityId" key="true" />
    <cf:property name="EntityC" typeName="{0}.NamespaceC.EntityC" />
  </cf:entity>
  <cf:entity name="EntityC" namespace="Model1.NamespaceC">
    <cf:property name="EntityCId" key="true" />
  </cf:entity>
  <cf:producer name="SQL Server Pivot Script" typeName="CodeFluent.Producers.SqlServer.SqlPivotScriptProducer, CodeFluent.Producers.SqlServer">
    <cf:configuration targetDirectory="..\Database1" connectionString="Server=127.0.0.1;Database=EntityA;Integrated Security=true;Application Name=Application;" cfx:targetProject="..\Database1\Database1.sqlproj" cfx:targetProjectLayout="Update" />
  </cf:producer>
  <cf:producer enabled="false" name="SQL Server" typeName="CodeFluent.Producers.SqlServer.SqlServerProducer, CodeFluent.Producers.SqlServer">
    <cf:configuration produceViews="true" targetDirectory="..\Database1" connectionString="Server=127.0.0.1;Database=EntityA;Integrated Security=true;Application Name=FedPeche33_Association;" cfx:targetProject="..\Database1\Database1.sqlproj" cfx:targetProjectLayout="Update, DontRemove" produceSchemas="true" />
  </cf:producer>
  <cf:producer enabled="false" name="Asp.Net Identity" typeName="CodeFluent.Producers.SqlServer.IxcysSqlPivotScriptProducer, SqlServerPivotIxcys">
    <cf:configuration targetDirectory="..\Database1" cfx:targetProject="..\Database1\Database1.sqlproj" cfx:targetProjectLayout="Update" connectionString="Server=127.0.0.1;Database=EntityA;Integrated Security=true;Application Name=FedPeche33_Association;" />
  </cf:producer>
</cf:project>
```

**Captured stacktrace:**

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in CodeFluent.Producers.SqlServer.dll
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

For the time being I would consider renaming my entities to go over this problem.
Thanks for your support

I also had this non-blocking exception on my environment while debugging pivot script generation:

```
DateTimeInvalidLocalFormat occurred
Message: Managed Debugging Assistant 'DateTimeInvalidLocalFormat' has detected a problem in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\SoftFluent\CodeFluent\Modeler\CodeFluent.Build4.exe'.
Additional information: A UTC DateTime is being converted to text in a format that is only correct for local times. This can happen when calling DateTime.ToString using the 'z' format specifier, which will include a local time zone offset in the output. In that case, either use the 'Z' format specifier, which designates a UTC time, or use the 'o' format string, which is the recommended way to persist a DateTime in text. This can also occur when passing a DateTime to be serialized by XmlConvert or DataSet. If using XmlConvert.ToString, pass in XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.RoundtripKind to serialize correctly. If using DataSet, set the DateTimeMode on the DataColumn object to DataSetDateTime.Utc.
```

Comment: To submit a bug about CodeFluent Entities, please fill in the form on the [SoftFluent Website](http://www.softfluent.com/support/). Stackoverflow should not be used as a bug tracker (<http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3966/is-it-okay-to-use-stack-overflow-as-the-support-forum-for-a-product-or-project>).

Comment: Morning, yes I'm aware about this, but here's the error message I have for the link given: SoftFluent, SoftFluent, we have a problem!
An unidentified error has occured.